# Increasing number after next combobox item selected

Tags: vb.net, combobox

What I want to do here is to increase the number on a label for next combobox item selected

eg.

```
Items              Label
Tom                 1
Jane                2
Mary                3
John                4
etc..               etc..
etc..               etc..
etc..               etc..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On selected index changed event set the value of the label as desired text.
Have alook on the code below:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

Select Case comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
Case "Tom"
   label1.text="1"
Case "Jane"
    label1.text="2"

' And so on
End Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: but when I select the item "Tom" again it will increase by one

Comment: So you want to show 1 for tom, 2 for jane etc? Check the updated answer.

Comment: yea this is what I meant. Another question, so let say if I were to add another item onto the combobox from another form, how do I assign the numbers?

Comment: You can store the names and corresponding numbers in database. Then retrive or assign data(the numbers in your case) asnd show this data in the event.

Comment: I think you mistook what I was trying to say. What I was trying to say is that for every new item added into the combobox the label will +1 from the previous number

Comment: For every new item in the combobox..there should be corresponding code in the event. So in your case every time you add an item write the code for it in the event.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7604/discussion-between-completenewb-and-geek-on-demand)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is that you can implement the auto-increment option or You can also code it using any iterative loop, just like for loop or while loop giving the constraint of not reaching the end of the database..